# Logos subclass of private runtime class

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, cydia-substrate, logos

I am trying to implement a tweak for iOS7 Control Center that involves adding additional section. So I want to make subclass of `SBControlCenterSectionViewController` but I get linker errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBControlCenterSectionViewController", referenced from:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBControlCenterSectionViewController", referenced from:
```

As far as I understand that's because I don't have implementation for SB private frameworks (only headers), but is there is a way to make a subclass of SBControlCenterSectionViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%subclass MySubclass: SBControlCenterSectionViewController

- (void)anExistingMethodInSuperclass
{
    //...
}

%new
- (void)aNewMethodInSubclass
{
    //...
}

%end
```